# Failing Batch class : First error: List has no rows for assignment to SObject and running batch class with size 1

Tags: batch, batchapexerrorevent

```
global class BatchForLatestCaseOHVRDatesAccountField implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

      // Start Method

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 

        return Database.getQueryLocator( [Select ID from Account where ID IN ( '0018000000YFjri','0018000000UoAuO') ]) ;
    }

    global static void updateAccountDetails(List<Account> lstAccs){

        string accountIds;
        accountIds = (String)lstAccs.get(0).ID;

        Case cs = New case();
        cs = [ select ID,AccountId,createddate from Case where accountid =: accountIds order by createddate desc limit 1 ];
        Order_History__c orh = New Order_History__c(); 
        orh = [ select ID,Account__c ,createddate from Order_History__c where Account__c  = : accountIds order by createddate desc limit 1 ];
        Visit_Report__c vr = New  Visit_Report__c(); 
        vr= [ select ID,Account_ID__c ,createddate from Visit_Report__c where Related_Account__c   = :accountIds order by createddate desc limit 1 ];
        List<Account> lstacc = [Select ID, Latest_Case_Created_Date__c,Latest_OrderHistory_Created_Date__c,Latest_VisitReport_Created_Date__c from Account where ID = :accountIds ];

        // Case Update

        for(Account acc : lstacc){

                    if(cs != NULL)
                    acc.Latest_Case_Created_Date__c  = cs.createddate;
                    if(orh != NULL)
                    acc.Latest_OrderHistory_Created_Date__c  = orh.createddate;
                    if(vr != NULL)
                    acc.Latest_VisitReport_Created_Date__c  = vr.createddate;

        }
        Update lstacc;

        List<Contact> con = [SELECT ID,Name FROM CONTACT where AccountID = :accountIds];
        UPDATE con;   


    }
    // Execute Logic
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){

        updateAccountDetails(scope);

    }


    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        // Logic to be Executed at finish
    }


}
```

Comment: please see [ask] --specifically, which query?

Comment: Don't use hard-coded ids. Don't use global access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly one of the query is returning null result. Instead use a list of sObject for your queries and take the 0th element to avoid such errors.

Comment: Acctually I need to update all existing records

Answer (score 0):

check the list size() before doing for loop and DML operations like below. your issue with either `list<account>` / `list<contact>`. and you should create list instance first.

```
List<Account> lstacc = new List<Account>();
lstacc  = [Select ID, Latest_Case_Created_Date__c,Latest_OrderHistory_Created_Date__c,Latest_VisitReport_Created_Date__c from Account where ID = :accountIds ];
if(lstacc.size() > 0){
 for(Account acc : lstacc){

                    if(cs != NULL)
                    acc.Latest_Case_Created_Date__c  = cs.createddate;
                    if(orh != NULL)
                    acc.Latest_OrderHistory_Created_Date__c  = orh.createddate;
                    if(vr != NULL)
                    acc.Latest_VisitReport_Created_Date__c  = vr.createddate;

        }

        Update lstacc;
}


   List<Contact> conlist = new List<Contact>();
   conlist = [SELECT ID,Name FROM CONTACT where AccountID = :accountIds];
  if(conlist.size() > 0){
     UPDATE con;
   }
```